# Image not showing up in the browser

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

Here's what Im trying to do.. The images I save on the database are going to the correct path. But they don't show up in the site.

```
@blogs.route("/post/new", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_post():
    if ('user' in session and session['user'] == params["username"]):
        form = PostForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            pic = save_picture(request.files['pic'])
            post = Post(title=form.title.data,
                        content=form.content.data, img=pic)
            db.session.add(post)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Your post has been created!', 'success')
            image_file = url_for('static', filename = 'profile_pics/' + pic)
            return render_template('post.html',image_file=image_file)
        
        return render_template('create_post.html', title='New Post',
                               form=form)
    return "please login to the dashboard first. Dont try to enter without logging in!"
```

The HTML side

```
<img src="{{image_file}}" alt="error">
```

Comment: That did not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found a fix!!**

I figured out that one can use the set keyword from python as a variable to store the post.img in it and then refer it inside the source.

```
{% set img_name = 'profile_pics/' + post.img %}

<img src="{{url_for('static', filename = img_name)}}" alt="error">
```

Comment: Came to use again

Answer (score 0):

This would be the route function:

```py
image_file = url_for('static', filename='profile_pics/' + post.img)
return render_template('template.html', image_file=image_file)
```

and this is what it looks like in the template:

```html
<img src="{{ image_file }}">
```

The issue is probably that You are not really able to have nested variables inside html especially because jinja probably interpreted that as a literal string

Comment: I want to show you my code where do I do so?...I think its mistake on my side

Comment: @A-d-ash post the code in Your question, You can edit Your question to do so, but did You try the solution I showed here?

Comment: Yes sir I did try that

Comment: @A-d-ash `image_file=image_file`

Comment: Ohh that was a silly mistake.. But no luck.. It did not work

Comment: @A-d-ash can You show the `save_picture()` function?

Comment: I you have some doubts about other areas where I could have made a mistake, you can suggest me. I will look up to them.

Comment: Yupp.. I did it

Comment: @A-d-ash what did You do? did You manage to show the picture?

Comment: Noo the save_picture function i have showned above

Comment: I noticed something, instead of redirecting them to `'post'` as You should when they have created a new post, You render the template

Comment: Ok,, so when in my blog posting process, when I choose an image and hit upload, I am redirected to the same route /post/new and it's showing the picture there!. But i want it to show up in the post.html page.. This is weird.

Comment: @A-d-ash yep, that is what I thought is happening, it shows for a short moment immediately after submitting the form, btw are You following Corey Schafer's tutorials? the reason it shows only after submitting the form is because then You render a template with that image, in all other cases You render template without `image_file`, the best to do is probably to redirect them to a different route that always shows the `image_file`

Comment: Yeah, man.I am making my project and following him...I will make a new route for the individual posts page and return here if there is any problem. Thanks.. Is there any place I can follow you? You seem like a nice guy to follow

Comment: @A-d-ash not really, You can't follow, this site is not meant for that, otherwise it is possible tho that if You post any further questions You can  also add a comment here linking to that question, good luck

Comment: Finally!  I fixed this thing.

Comment: @A-d-ash great, how did You do it? You may even post an answer Yourself so that people in the future can see the solution

Comment: Yeah i posted it above

Comment: @A-d-ash ok, but it would be great if You posted it as an answer and then probably mark as correct or sth

Comment: Oh yeah.. Thanks. I  did not notice that there was such an option. 

Comment: It says i have to wait at least 2 days.

Comment: @A-d-ash well, at least You got the upvote for now, but You should then really mark it as the correct answer after those two days because otherwise for example it isn't possible to mark a question as a duplicate if there are no accepted answers on the question that is the duplicate